# Unable to subset data in a shapefile

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, rgdal

I would like to carry out a subsetting in my shapefile without specifying the name of the first column in the .dbf file. 
To be more precise I would like to select all the rows with value 1 in the first column of the .dbf, but I don't want to specify the name of this column.

For example this script works because I specify the name of the column (as columnName)

```
library(rgdal) # readOGR

shapeIn <- readOGR(nomeFile)
shapeOut <- subset(shapeIn, columnName == 1)
```

instead it doesn't works

```
shapeOut <- (shapeIn[,1] == 1)
```

and I get an error message:
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types shapeOut and shapeIn are ESRI vector files.

This is the header of my shapeIn

```
   coordinates mask_1000_
1 (54000, 1218000)          0
2 (55000, 1218000)          0
3 (56000, 1218000)          0
```

Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Dear community, my post, entitled "Unable to subset data in a shapefile" has been downvoted 4 times. Nonetheless the problem has been positively solved by LoBu on November 24. Could you please specify what  do I have to do to remove my ban, because I would like to be able to use again the forum. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
shapeOut <- (shapeIn[,1] == 1)
```

doesn't work beacuse SpatialPolygonsDataFrames contain other info other than the data. So "common" data.frame subsetting doesn't work in the same way. To have it work, you must make the "logical check" for subsetting on the @data slot: this  should work (either using subset or "direct" indexing):

```
shapeOut <- subset(shapeIn, shapeIn@data[,1] == 1)
```

OR

```
shapeOut <- shapeIn[shapeIn@data[,1] == 1,]
```

(however, by recent experience, referencing to data by column number is seldom a good idea... ;-) )

ciao Giacomo !!!